# Compilation error with play 2 framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to learn play framework, while practicing sample code I am getting an error: "illegal start of simple expression"

```
     @main("TODO list")
4{
5   <h1>@tasks.size() task(s)</h1>
6   <ul>
7       @for(task <- tasks)
```

Error is shown in line 7, I have no idea why it is

Comment: Maybe you forgot the '{': `@for(task <- tasks){`

Comment: Show us whole template please (not only error message).

Comment: @nico_ekito - you are right, the problem is with "{", earlier it was in newline,now I kept it in same line like "@for(task <- tasks){" and it is working. Thanks.

Comment: why having braces in next line create compiler error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the '{' character at the following line:

```
@for(task <- tasks){
```

It is needed on the same line by the Scala template engine to ensure that the '{' comes from the templating language, and that it is not a HTML character.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering why { is need to be in same line, and you gave the answer here.